# Cloudfront removes Set-Cookie header from response to viewer

Tags: cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have a NextJs application running in an AWS EC2 instance. The application includes static pages and APIs for login. Now, I am trying to setup AWS Cloudfront distribution. However, I am facing a challenge because CloudFront removes the Set-Cookie header from the login API Response and it's breaking the login functionality.

Below is the reference of the cache behavior setup in which I have disabled caching for the `/api/*` path.

| Precedence | Path pattern | Cache policy name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | /api/* | Managed-CachingDisabled |
| 1 | Default (*) | Managed-CachingOptimized |

After referring AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html, I have noticed that it's possible to forward cookies from viewer to origin.

But, it's still not clear to me,

1. How to forward the `Set-Cookie` header from the origin response to viewer.
2. Why CloudFront removes the `Set-Cookie header` for the path `/api/*` in which caching has been disabled.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: > How to forward the Set-Cookie header from the origin response to viewer - this header has to be set by your server. Once set, Cloudfront will automatically forward it to the viewer.

Comment: > Why CloudFront removes the Set-Cookie header - Caching based on cookies and forwarding cookies to the origin in an Origin Request are not directly related to each other though, if you cache on cookies, those cookies also get forwarded to the origin. Caching and Origin Requests are managed by separate policies.

Comment: My application is already set the `Set-Cookie` header. But, it's removed by Cloudfront without forwarding it to viewer.

Comment: ```Don’t forward cookies to your origin – CloudFront doesn’t cache your objects based on cookie sent by the viewer. In addition, CloudFront removes cookies before forwarding requests to your origin, and removes Set-Cookie headers from responses before returning responses to your viewers.``` - This what I see in CloudFront [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html)

Comment: What you quoted is one option on how to handle cookies. Above the quoted part are two other options - to forward all and to forward some. Did you by chance think that the quoted part is CF’s ultimate behavior?

Comment: I have tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017860/returning-response-with-set-cookie-header-in-aws-cloudfront-origin-request) and it has helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs